# Also show row with NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql

When I hit the below code without where clause, it shows row with `NULL` value but when I put where clause like below then there is no row with `NULL` value.

I want the row with `NULL` value with where clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM project_category as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  project_estimate_detail  as b 
  ON a.id = b.project_cat_id 
where b.project_cat_id not in ('21','22','2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM project_category as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  project_estimate_detail  as b 
   ON a.id = b.project_cat_id 
where (b.project_cat_id IS NULL) OR (b.project_cat_id not in ('21','22','2'))
```

When `b.project_cat_id` is `NULL` then `NOT IN` evaluates to `NULL`. So you have to *explicitly* check for `NULL` using the `IS NULL` expression.

Comment: @DurgeshPandey I think I tried to explain: `NULL NOT IN ('21','22','2')` yields `NULL` as a result **not** false. This is called [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   project_category AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN project_estimate_detail AS b
                    ON a.id = b.project_cat_id
WHERE  b.project_cat_id NOT IN ( '21', '22', '2' )
       AND b.project_cat_id IS NULL
```

Comment: But why ...M not stopping the null value

Answer (score 1):

You join on `a.id = b.project_cat_id` and then filter on the *inner* table, `b.project_cat_id`, which removes all the NULLs.

Simply change your `WHERE`-condition to use the join column from the *outer* table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM project_category as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  project_estimate_detail  as b 
  ON a.id = b.project_cat_id 
WHERE a.id not in ('21','22','2')
```